# Measure RC Circuit Time Constant Without Oscilloscope?

Tags: arduino, circuit-analysis, capacitor, resistors, adc

I'm looking on working demonstration to experimentally visualize the voltage on a capacitor as it's being charged and discharged. Unfortunately, I don't have a oscilloscope accessible to me, so I'm looking to the use the ADC of the Arduino as a makeshift oscilloscope.

I currently have three circuits(falstad circuit links included). Wherever I have a voltmeter present, one lead is meant to present the ADC of the Arduino and the other, the ground of Arduino.

Here is [circuit 1](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgoqoQFMBaMMAKACcQ9jDwMeue2bDyoo0cFgHdOcEEP7c5wqFJlUALGAU9NI1QKXaQuldPWF1h47PmnjF41usankVetkmPVW27M3lb149ADc1KwQ%20KyoNWih4mAQWAGMKdUswKL48YJAUKFh4SFIS0rLSY2gShDxIdQwxYjA8XEsYOFZpBHTcoMy9aWzcg367SJ0nWpc9AGd7SxNxxxFwEAAXNgBXOhY580tbJd9Vje2WAAc0jJ6hsB6IGNVu68tn3L8QW5vCHNG3AHsQMQQA5YhUkO14GRCAhCCgIXkgXIWEA):
[image]

For this one, I'm hoping to charge the capacitor directly with the Arduino 5v pin. I think the current should be manageable, but are there any other issue with this one? I think the impedance of the ADC should stop the ADC from too much current running through the Arduino, as well as not disturb the charge on the capacitor too much, but I'm not certain about this.

Here is [circuit 2](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEBmAHAJmgdgGzoRmACzICcpkORICkNNdCApgLRhgBQATiKqTuFy9%20KZALpg4HAO684ogXwHIxUGXLpEwikVvHqlC4QL1rZRKkaLyV%2085dPXN2syCduX7266%20r3YIUgOADcNIwQhbzpNCVIoeJgEDgBjGiJqAIFcVEEBdChYdCJyEtKynLBUaHJUIgIi2iwEAnFYSE5ZBHTct3lM12yew36gzqFTVHlTIIAHN2R89nycSAqwRYT1Lozu7Z7RkEHiaiPAjgBnN0tvCOVVaJAAMwBDABtzpgur6lNbj3FwE83h9uCAcAgBMdDjgKt0JPB4KC9lDwZC4W4sAj1KjwN0cUsfAtwOtehISQd-OM%20uTsaticsIfS1AB7EBxSwxcggdDRNpwUi4CH4eL5OLIDhAA):[image]
For this one, I'm looking to demonstrate quite a high capacitance capacitor, which requires being charged by an external power supply, which goes up to 19 volts. As a result, I put a voltage divider to avoid pushing the ADC past its rated voltage. I've placed the largest resistance resistors I have to again avoid disturbing the reading, but do any other issues exist with this one?

Here is [circuit 3](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEBmAHAJmgdgGzoRmACzICcpkORICkNNdCApgLRhgBQATiKqTuFy9%20KZALpEscDgHdecUQL4DkYqLPkSwSkUW3q5yxcIF7xGolWNEFq83MvUzIG1vsuFz18cgXba7zAhXwA3TWMEITsoGJsUBTpE6AQOAGMaImoggVxUQQF0KFh4clKy8vIQdFJUaBwwSDJ%20ZEssZEKYOE45BEz8jzpsgxBc-qMh3x6hZ1RPfV8ABxd28DBCnEg89kKIRI1erL6D-smRnC2%200YmOAGcXK2jIlTVEkAAzAEMAGxumW-unPoni55uB3t9ftwQDgEAJiNQrn1BvB4FDjvDobDwEjwCiNDC4X0CasOhYVtsBiThoFpgoKacNls1pi4czfAB7ECkaHUCSQSrtJIo0i4WH4GKFbnIDhAA):[image]

Finally, this last demo is a bit more tricky, since I'm salvaging a 300V disposable camera boost circuit?(not sure what it's called), and measuring the voltage across the capacitor that is charged for the flash tube. As a result, I've placed another voltage divider to step down the measured voltage. Besides the high voltages, would this circuit work?

Comment: You may want to consider getting an oscilloscope. A proper entry-level scope from Rigol or Siglent will run you about $400, but you can get cheap handheld ones for about $80, and sometimes you can find old analog scopes on ebay or at estate sales for like $20.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use a higher voltage?  Why not just use the available 5V output? for all the examples?  The time constant will be the same even with 5V.  Also note that with the voltage divider (resistors) across the cap the time constant of the circuit will be affected, (you would need to include the resistor divider in the calculation).

Comment: @Nedd For the last example, it's mainly because the capacitor already has a charging circuit attached to it, so I figured it'd be easier to just use the included circuit, but I could switch to only using the 5V VCC. I thought, given the high resistance of the voltage divider, the impact on the time constant would be small though?

Comment: You really don't want to be fiddling with an exposed 300V circuit.  That's asking for trouble.

Comment: The circuits are upside down from the general convention. You usually keep the ground references between things same instead of referencing to 5V supply, but is there a reason for that? Also the voltager dividers load down and discharge the capacitor so it must be calculated. Also ADC inputs gulp current when they sample the input so it will affect the reading. The ADC also needs low enough impedance on input so it can't sample through many hundred kilo-ohms of impedance.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using only a 5V supply and the Arduino analog input channel to read a 0V to 5V signal, then (since you don't have a scope) use the Aruduino serial output to a lap top serial port. Read the serial text, convert to numbers, then plot the values on a XY time chart using any simple charting software, (even MS Excel). You could even use the lap top (with Excel) to calculate the actual measured RC time constant after each run.

In case that's not challenging enough, purchase a low cost OLED display for the Arduino, download some github software for the OLED, then create your own plot of the RC curve.